# How to suppress windows system message

Tags: visual-c++

I have created a application which copies files from hard disk to Floppy drive using the CopyFile() API.
In the middle of the copy process for a large file, if the floppy is removed from the drive then windows
system popup's up an error message.

I want to suppress this error message that is popped up by the system. I googled and read about SetErrorMode() API used 
by many applications to solve similar issues and tried using it with all the possible flag options but it fails. Sample code -

UINT uOldErrorMode = SetErrorMode (SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
::CopyFile("C:\text.dat","A:\text.dat", FALSE);
SetErrorMode (uOldErrorMode);

SetErrorMode() API fails to suppress the error message. Can anyone help me in understanding why is it not working with for my application?

I then came across the below link : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128642 which talks about the key

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows\ErrorMode

whose value can be set to 0,1 or 2 to suppress or show the error messages. This solution works for my application but I feel that

a. It is not a good programming practices to access the system key directly? there should be a API that should do this.
b. Such a code shall fail the UAC when executed on Windows Vista or Windows 7.

Can anybody please provide some help with the above issue.

Regards,
Felix

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work or not, but what about trying [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the `FOF_NOERRORUI` flag?

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite an answer but some more information based on my experience.  I found SetErrorMode seemed to work on Windows Vista and Windows 7.  It did not work in Windows XP.  XP would still pop up error messages for a simple ...memory could not be "read"... crash.  This was a killer for my use in a distributed processing unattended situation.  The article referenced in the question saved my bacon with a fix.

I still suffer from the part of the question about programticly modifying the registry.  For my case I don't need to worry because SetErrorMode worked in 7 and vista (yet), but If it didn't I would just test to see if letting windows set it in the virtual store would also give the correct behavior.